# how can i add billing information in invoice email

Tags: rules, emails, tokens, commerce

I have been using commerce Invoice 7x-10-alfa3
commerce Email 7x-2x-dev
Variable email 7x-10-alpha -1x
Variable 7x-22,4-dev
HTML 7.x-2.65 modules

I want to sent an invoice email, which will include except of the order information
(included in the token [commerce-order:commerce-email-order-items] ) , also the billing information address (I need all the information as it is appearing in the order view).

However, even though i try two different tokens [commerce-invoice:order:commerce-customer-billing:commerce_customer_address] and
[commerce-order:commerce-customer-billing] none of the them renders any data but they just appear as simple strings!. Also other tokens i added in the body of the email, are just displayed as simple strings. I trying to modify the  "default" value of the email through the store->configuration->emails

From what i have seen there is an issue with commerce email ,which have not been yet resolved https://drupal.org/node/1818380 . I was wondering whether someone has found a workround solution i can use.

Failing that is there any other way i could achieve the same result ? (To be able to sent an invoice email with order details and complete billing information). Maybe a combination of tokens in rules with different  modules (or different versions of modules).

As i am pretty desperate any suggestions would be more than welcome.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented similar functionality for a Drupal Commerce site I built using Commerce Kickstart 2. It's actually a Rule created by the **commerce_email** module which I'll break down for you below:

- **Rule is called "Send an order notification e-mail (Customers)"**
- **Event: Completing the checkout process**
- **Action: Send mail with variable (contains all default commerce_email variable settings)**

Then if you navigate to the Commerce Email admin section: **(/admin/commerce/config/email)**

The token I use to display the customer address is:

**[commerce-order:commerce-customer-shipping:commerce_customer_address]**

Using that token everything prints out in my email template correctly as expected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I would prefer to try everything else first, and then to try to  "migrate" to KickStart 2.

Comment: You don't need Commerce Kickstart to use this implementation. Commerce Kickstart is just an installation profile for Drupal Commerce. These rules are created by the module commerce_email, but you can create them yourself if you prefer too.

Comment: The thing is that when i try to add the tokens to the rules that commerce_email creates, they do not  render any data but they just appear as  strings. The same is true with the Token you posted.Thanks again for your help